# How to upload image captured from camera to firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload the image captured from camera to firebase Storage. I know how to store the image once I get the Uri format of image but I am getting Bitmap from camera activity. So I need to know how to do that?

```
click_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,2);
            }
        });

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
public String getFileExtendsion(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return  mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }
public void uploadFile(){
        if(mImageUri!=null){
            final StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child("ProfilePicture"+"."+getFileExtendsion(mImageUri));
            fileReference.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            ///store the uri
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Fail",e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I have function uploadFile() to store the Uri of image to firebase storage and then get the url of the image to store it in firebase realtime database. But do I need to convert the bitmap to Uri? If yes, how? The code I found isn't working and if there's any other way please tell me!
Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a bitmap from the camera, see the first example in the Firebase documentation showing how [upload from data that you have in memory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory), which conveniently starts with a `Bitmap`.

From there:

> ```
> // Get the data from an ImageView as bytes
> imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
> imageView.buildDrawingCache();
> Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
> ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
> bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
> byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
>
> UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
> ```

Comment: Yes thanks! But that example gives the Uri file after saving it on the device to a particular path but I don't want to store it on the device. What should I do?